# positive charge on oxygen of carbonyl group in acetic acid

Tags: hyperconjugation

I refer to a previous post by Ron on hyper conjugation in acetic acid(Link:https://chemistry stack exchange.com/.../hyper conjugation in-in-acetic-acid)wherein it is stated that "In acetic acid there is a partial positive charge on carbonyl oxygen". This is confusing me .How can oxygen carry a partial positive charge oxygen being highly electronegative?

Comment: In what post? Link? And what's your question really? Edit it!

Comment: Partial positive charge of oxygen of carbonyl group in acetic acid .

Comment: In a previous post by Mr. Ron "hyper conjugation of acetic acid ?" (Link- https://chemistry stack exchange.com/.../hyper conjugation-in-acetic acid")it s stated that "there is a partial positive charge on carbonyl oxygen ".How can oxygen hold a positive charge being electronegative?

Answer (score 1):

The carbon atom does not have a full positive charge like a carbocation. What happens when a carbon atom is bound to a more electronegative element such as oxygen, is that the electron density from the bond is higher towards oxygen then carbon, therefore leaving the carbon atom with a partial positive charge. When drawing the chemical structure of a carbonyl compound, you can indicate that the carbon atom has a partial positive charge and the oxygen has partial negative charge by using the greek letter sigma as in the picture:

[image: Carbonyl]

You can also see this through resonance structures for a carbonyl compound

[image]

The real molecule (the hybrid) is something between those two first structures in the left (they are called resonance structures and differ only by the electronic configuration around the atoms).